# Div with anchor tags to load php pages in another div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a div tag with many anchor tags in it. On clicking a lick it should open a php page in another div tag of the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2>Test</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="page1.php" class="active">page1</a>
            <a href="page2.php">page2</a>
            <a href="page3.php">page3</a>
            <a href="page4.php">page4</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content" >

        </div>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#myTopnav a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
                    var url = this.href;
                    $("#content").load(url);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a nav bar and on clicking the links it should load a php page in content div.  I tried the above code but it does not work.

Comment: What does not work ? does an error appear ?

Comment: how is this a php question?

Comment: When i click the link page 1 the page 1 does not load inside div with id content.

Comment: What does the Network activities say ? does a request goes out ? is this maybe a cross origin problem ?

Comment: Yes exactly. jquery.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/website/menu.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. Kindly let me know how i should correctbit

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working for you, try the full context and see what the error message might be:

```
$( "#content" ).load( url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
    if ( status == "error" ) {
        window.alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Google developer tools says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in that line. and the page does not load in the div id content

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is that its a local file at your system, you need to set up a webserver.
If the problem exist further then you can add "Cross Origin" headers to the called php files.

Comment: yes this works. Thank you. Now I have a different problem when i load a php page into div tag the dataTables and angular modules are removed from it and only the html content loads.

Comment: Then you should Put the content into a other div element. Pleas create another question and Mark this one as solution